# Displacement x of a system

Tags: applications

Displacement x of a system satisfies
$$
3\ddot{x}+8\dot{x}+5x=43+2y-7\dot{y}
$$
where $y=4\cos(t)$. If $x=0=$ $\dot{x}$ at $t=0$, find $x $and describe the motion that occurs at large times.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse15.html

Comment: Try to guess a solution and use it to find the actual solution to this problem(just like we do to solve diophantine equations)

Comment: Sorry should've mentioned that. I did ansatz to find lambda. Using the equation y=yh+yp (h and p are subscript). Not sure if I got the coefficients correct and what I'm supposed to do after that.

Comment: Try linearity and superposition for particular solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the homogeneous part of the equation we get $$x(t)=e^{-5/3t}C_1+C_2e^{-t}$$ for the particular solution make the ansatz $$x_p(t)=A+B\cos(t)+C\sin(t)$$